# Kubernetes custom jenkins chart throws error associated with override_config_map

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to spin up jenkins server using latest jenkins.1.3.6 version helm chart. However, when applying the chart I am receiving the `error calling include: template: no template "override_config_map" associated with template "gotpl"`

> Error: render error in
>   "my-chart/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml":
>   template:my-chart/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml:42:28:
>   executing
>   "my-chart/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml" at
>   : error calling
>   include: template:
>   my-chart/charts/jenkins/templates/config.yaml:335:3: executing
>   "my-chart/charts/jenkins/templates/config.yaml" at : error calling include: template: no template
>   "override_config_map" associated with template "gotpl"

Comment: could you please add more details on the flags that you are using to deploy.

Comment: In my Values.yaml file I have set `customConfigMap: true` and inside the `charts/jenkins/templates/config.yaml` there is Code snippet which include the override_config_map code `{{ else }}
{{ include "override_config_map" . }}
{{- end -}}
{{- if .Values.master.additionalConfig }} ` .  However when I execute helm lint then I get above error.

Comment: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins#custom-configmap

custom config map will be deprecated in the future. FYI

Comment: You have to copy config.yaml to templates/config.tpl as mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

As [fdlk](https://github.com/fdlk) mentioned in the comment to the [CustomConfigMap option yields error with override_config_map missing #4040](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/4040) :

> It helped me to run `helm lint my-chart` to figure out how many brackets I needed.
> My `config.tpl` now looks like this:

```
{{- define "override_config_map" }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
[...]
  plugins.txt: |-
{{- if .Values.Master.InstallPlugins }}
{{- range $index, $val := .Values.Master.InstallPlugins }}
{{ $val | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

> Using 0.16.4